# Timestamps for Trace.Debug.trace calls

Tags: trace, ghc, event-log

In GHC we can `trace` to get some debug information but I would love a timestamp for traces for profiling mostly and sometimes debugging purposes. I tried looking into GHC eventlog but couldn't find the events raised by `trace`.